# How to post data from several rows that have same dropdown menu?

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

I have this kind of table

```
+----------------------------------+
|ID     Company      Staff Name    |
|1        Co A       DropDown Menu |
|2        Co B       DropDown Menu |
|3        Co c       DropDown Menu |
+----------------------------------+
+-------------+
|Submit Button|
+-------------+
```

I need to update each of the ID to the staff name related
This is my dropdown select

```html
<td align="center">
<?PHP 
$html='<select name="staff[]" >';
while($row =DB_FetchRow($rs_staff)) {
    $html .= '<option value='.$row["staff_id"].'>' .$row["staff_name"] . '</option>';
}

$html .= '</select>';
echo $html; ?></td>
```

And this is my POST

```html
<!-- language-all: lang-html -->

if ((isset($_POST["Submit"])) && ($_POST["Submit"] =="Save")) {

    foreach($_POST['staff'] as $key => $myname){

        //here goes all the related code.

   }//if mysqli_fetch_array condition closed

}// for loop closed
```

I could update the table but if update row ID=2 it will update the first row.How can I update the row tat I selected.
Hope someone could help me as i am new to PHP.

Comment: you want only the selected option to be updated?

Comment: yes,but it always update the first row of the table if i update the second row.